# How to slow down an index operation in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Index operations in MongoDB are executed instantaneously and can cause a high additional load on the DB for large collection, for example adding an index.

Is there a way to slow down such operations which do not need to be executed instantaneously and distribute them over a longer time spam?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `background` index building option or upgrade to server v4.2 as described in the official docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#options).

```java
  db.collection.createIndex({"fieldName" : 1}, {"background" : 1});
```